# Jquery parse and save part of XML in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an XML which I am parsing using jquery, it works but I want to only get part of the XML data and then save all that part in localstorage.

My xml looks like this

```
<channel id="123"><display-name>123</display-name></name></channel>
<channel id="123"><display-name>123</display-name></name></channel>
<channel id="123"><display-name>123</display-name></name></channel>
<programme id="123"><display-name>123</display-name></name></programme>
<programme id="123"><display-name>123</display-name></name></programme>
<programme id="123"><display-name>123</display-name></name></programme>
```

But I only want to get all the `<programme>` data and then save that to localstorage. Im not sure how I can only grab the programme sections.

I have tried saving the whole xml but that didnt seem to output any data. This is what what I have tried.

```
<div id="text"></div>

$(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/myxml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){

window.localStorage.setItem('fullxml', xml)
$("#text").append(window.localStorage.getItem('fullxml'));

  },
  error: function() {
    alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: Try to console logging the result in the ajax success function. Do you get any response?

Comment: xml is an xml document, assuming everything else is working, so you can traverse it with jquery, eg `$(xml).find("programme")`

Answer (score 3):

To get a specific node from an XML document, you can select the XML node like this:

**Javascript:**

```
var programmeNodes = fullxml.getElementsByTagName('programme');
```

**jQuery:**

```
var programmeNodes = $(fullxml).find('programme');
```

**My Solution:**

This solution grabs all `<programme>` nodes and saves the data into an array and then stores that array in local storage for later use.

Given XML data like this:

```
var xml = `
    <programmes>
        <programme id="1">
            <display-name>Test 1</display-name>
        </programme>
        <programme id="2">
            <display-name>Test 2</display-name>
        </programme>
  </programmes>
`;
```

Will give an array of objects like this which can then be stored.

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: Test1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: Test2
    }
]
```

Full demo code:

```
var xml = `
    <programmes>
        <programme id="1">
            <display-name>Test 1</display-name>
        </programme>
        <programme id="2">
            <display-name>Test 2</display-name>
        </programme>
    </programmes>
`;

var fullxml = $.parseXML(xml);

// find <programme> XML elements

var programmeNodes = $(fullxml).find('programme');

// create array for programme data

var programmesArr = [];

// loop through each programme and store data in array

$.each(programmeNodes, function(i) {
    var programmeID = $(programmeNodes[i]).attr('id');
  var programmeDisplayName = $(programmeNodes[i]).find('display-name').text();
  programmesArr.push({
    id: programmeID,
    name: programmeDisplayName
  });
});

// store programmesArr in local storage
// localStorage only allows strings, so we need to convert array to JSON string

localStorage.setItem('programmes', JSON.stringify(programmesArr));

// get programmes from local storage

var storedProgrammes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('programmes'));
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/1nLw7hjr/13/

**Usage:**

```
var programmeToFind = 2;

var programme = $.grep(storedProgrammes, function(e) {
    return e.id == programmeToFind;
});

console.log(programme[0].id); // 2
console.log(programme[0].name); // Test2
```

Or as a little function:

```
function searchProgrammes(id) {
    var programme = $.grep(storedProgrammes, function(e) {
        return e.id == id;
    });
    return programme[0];
}

var programme = searchProgrammes(2);

console.log(programme.id); // 2
console.log(programme.name); // Test2
```

[**grep()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

> Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The
>   original array is not affected.

Comment: Thanks that works, using the method to get the data back out, how could I filter the data to get the "id" of a programme node?

Comment: Actually the json data is just showing {} nothing is inside each object

Comment: its like this {"0"}:{}, {"2"}:{}, {"3"}:{}, etc

Comment: @brandbei37 - I updated my answer to demonstrate a better way.

Comment: yes that works now and if i wanted to grab all the data from a certain id, how do i output it? so if the id was "channel1" how could i output all channel 1 data?

Comment: @brandbei37 - please see 'Usage' section of my updated answer.

Comment: no output data, it keeps saying "programme[0] is undefined" in the console, my programme id is text, example id="chan1"

Comment: @brandbei37 - Please take a look at the demo here which shows it working with 'chan1', 'chan2' as ID: https://jsfiddle.net/1nLw7hjr/13/. Obviously, it outputs to console.log so check your log when using the demo. I did actually make a small mistake in the function I made in the 'Usage' section but updated now.

Comment: Its working, but one last thing, it outputs only the first id, how can it output all data for that id?

Comment: @brandbei37 - It already does that;  `var programme = searchProgrammes('chan2')` -- `programme` now contains all programme data for `chan2`. It's in array format.

Comment: @brandbei37: see this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/o4y0fqgt/1/ I have added a way to show all programme data at the bottom of the demo that uses `$.each()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't get any response because when you append the XML to the document, the browser try to parse it, and because this isn't valid HTML, it fails and show only the text, not the tags. So, the simplest solution will to not use jQuery's `append()` method, and instead, append the XML via `text()` (that doesn't parse the HTML tags, and instead escapes them), like:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/myxml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('fullxml', xml);
      var el = $("#text");
      el.text(el.text() + window.localStorage.getItem('fullxml'));
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
    }
  });
});
```

#### Edit:

If you want to store only some elements, you should convert the XML to objects. Use `DOMParser`, as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/myxml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      var xmldoc;

      if (window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmldoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
      } else { // Internet Explorer
        xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmldoc.async = false;
        xmldoc.loadXML(xml);
      }

      var programmes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('programme');
      var str = '';
      programmes.forEach(function(el) {
        str += el.outerHTML;
      });
      // str now contains only the <programme> elements
      window.localStorage.setItem('fullxml', str);
      var el = $("#text");
      el.text(el.text() + window.localStorage.getItem('fullxml'));
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: How can I just save the <programme> nodes using this? at the moment it works, but its saving the whole xml, i tried adding, fullxml.getElementsByTagName('programme') but it didnt work

Comment: This is didn't work because `fullxml` is a string, not a DOM element. But you can convert it to a dom element - I'll edit my answer.